# PayPal API: curl request to PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am trying to add PayPal payment on my website using cURL and I found how to get the access token but I don't get how to transform this request (gave by PayPal Developer) into PHP cURL to proceed to payment.

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>' \
-d '{
  "intent":"sale",
  "redirect_urls":{
    "return_url":"http://example.com/your_redirect_url.html",
    "cancel_url":"http://example.com/your_cancel_url.html"
  },
  "payer":{
    "payment_method":"paypal"
  },
  "transactions":[
    {
      "amount":{
        "total":"7.47",
        "currency":"USD"
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like that (not tested):

```
$ch = curl_init('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>'
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$payloadData = '{
  "intent":"sale",
  "redirect_urls":{
    "return_url":"http://example.com/your_redirect_url.html",
    "cancel_url":"http://example.com/your_cancel_url.html"
  },
  "payer":{
    "payment_method":"paypal"
  },
  "transactions":[
    {
      "amount":{
        "total":"7.47",
        "currency":"USD"
      }
    }
  ]
}';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payloadData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$httpStatusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: bet he will get an issue with CURLOPT_VERIFYPEER next :p